# Replace a value of a row by another if null in Apache Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I use Apache Spark 1.6.2 in Java.

I have a DataFrame containing:

- a date in a creation_date field,
- an end date in a close_date field.

If the business is not closed, then the value in close_date is null.

I would like to:

- add an extra column to my DataFrame called last_date_business
- fill it with the value of close_date
- if close_date is null, then use current_date()

Can I ask Spark to do it or should I do it manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need here is a `coalesce`:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

df.withColumn("last_date_business", coalesce(col("close_date"), current_date()));
```

Comment: What is the equivalent in java?

Comment: @zero323 , I am using spark-sql -2.4.1v , i dont find coalesce() function ... what is the alternative I can use ? please suggest.